# Is reactivecocoa for swift is bidirectional data binding

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I am new to iOS development. I'd like to know whether reactivecocoa for swift support bidirectional data binding?

I tried https://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1 as my tutorial. Is there any way to data binding two directional?

Answer (score 0):

You need MutableProperty and DynamicProperty

```
DynamicProperty(object: segmentedControl, keyPath: "selectedSegmentIndex") <~ viewModel.segmented.producer.map { $0 }.observeOnMain()
viewModel.segmented <~ segmentedControl.rac_selectedChanged()
```